# file_put_contents and a new line and space

Tags: file-put-contents

After sending the string via the email i want to save it into file.
so i do it this way:

```
file_put_contents("coupon.txt", $email.  $RandomString  , FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```

and in this way it's look like this:

> email@email.com12d45f8e9email2@email2.com1d2d5s4d51d

so no new line and no space between the codes.
when i tray to use this way:

```
file_put_contents("coupon.txt", $email. .  $RandomString .PHP_EOL.  , FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```

it's just wont save anything, more then this is to error the mail sending.

Tal.

Comment: typo !  `$email. .` won't work try `$email .` and `PHP_EOL.` won't work either, remove this final dot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to append "\n", try this:

```
file_put_contents("coupon.txt", $email . "  " . $RandomString . "\n"  , FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```

Comment: PHP_EOL is ok for your situation, PHP_EOL is a cross-platform-compatible way, maybe you can try it.

Comment: file_put_contents("coupon.txt", $email . "  " . $RandomString . "\r\n"  , FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);

Answer (score 1):

use \t and \n in the string you want to write.

file_put_contents("coupon.txt", $email."\t". $RandomString . "\n"  , FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);

Comment: I use \t before, so use \n. Besides, everyone know the meaning. Acutally I don't know the type of PHP_EOL with out read the docs.

Comment: actually the only solution that works for me, thanks Yang